# rsync to copy files which has changed

Tags: rsync, file-copy

I need to copy some files from a particular directory to a different location on a daily basis. I want to copy the changes only, so planning to use `rsync`. These files follows the following naming convention `mysql-bin.*`

My command looks as follows

```
# rsync --update -raz --progress /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.*  /dbdata/binarylog/
```

My confusion is since I am planning to copy only few files from a directory rather than full directory contents , I have used `*`  to copy only required files. 
Just want to know whether my command is correct to achieve the same.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It looks OK.  Although why are you using the `-z` option to compress the transfer? This option is normally used when you are copying to a remote rsync server over a slow network. In this instance it will compress and instantly decompress the files which will only increase your CPU uage with no benefit.

The `-a` (archive) option implies the `-r` (recursive) option so there is no need to explicitly specify that on the command line.

You can use the `-n` option (or `--dry-run`) to check your command.  It will show what it would do without actually copying any files. To actually see what happens you should also use the `-v` option (or `--verbose`).

Therefore:

```
rsync -uanv /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.*  /dbdata/binarylog/
```

and once you're happy that the files are listed correctly on the dry-run, remove the `nv`:

```
rsync -ua --progress /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.*  /dbdata/binarylog/
```

Comment: As it says in the man page `--dry-run` flag is most commonly used in conjunction with the `--verbose` flag