# script for Monitor the file for changes

Tags: shell-script

Monitor the file for changes. If the file is changed, run a script to copy that file to other servers using scp or rsync.

i am looking for automatic script to copy the changes in the file from local server to another server ..

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with lsyncd. It's using inotify so is reacting very fast
even with big datasets.

https://github.com/axkibe/lsyncd

https://www.lucasrolff.com/ha/replication-using-lsyncd/

Answer (score 0):

rsync will only synchronize files that have been changed.
You can set up an rsync command that will synchronize every hour or at a specified time interval and it will only sync the files that have been changed.

Comment: do you have any script to  rsync only modify files ?                              Thanks for response

Comment: You can add something along the lines of this answer to a cronjob: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146282/rsync-to-copy-files-which-has-changed